# The problem of being parallel to $\mathbf y$ axis and undefined slope

Tags: linear-algebra

We all know the general equation for line $d$ is:
$d:y=ax+b$
I want you to suppose $d$ is parallel to $y$ axis.
Now , if we rearrange our equation , $x $will be equal to:
$$x=\frac{-b}{a}$$
It is clear that $a$ is undefined as line$d$ is parallel to $y$axis.But how $x$is equal to $-b$ over undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By explicit equation we can’t describe lines parallel to $y$ axis. Indeed in the explicit form

$$y=mx+n$$

$m$ represents the angular coefficient which $\to \infty$ for a vertical line thus this case can’t be described in such way.

For the general case we can refer to the implicit form

$$ax+by+c=0$$

which always holds.

Comment: It is right but, why it won't work in that form?

Comment: because it corresponds to an infinite angular coefficient

Comment: As an example try to find the expression in explicit form for a line through (1,0) and (1,2) by $y-0=(x-1)\frac{2-1}{1-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Comment: You are welcome, I had the same kind of doubt when faced first time with such kind of ambiguity. Bye

Answer (score 5):

"the general equation for line $d$ is: $d:y=ax+b$" This is not accurate. That's the general equation for a *linear function*, meaning that for each value of $x$ we get a unique value of $y$. This means that it specifically does not describe vertical lines, since for vertical lines there is only a single value of $x$ which works, and for that $x$-value there are infinitely many values for $y$.

A general equation for a line in the plane is
$$
ax + by = c
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are not both equal to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Comment: +1 but that's also inaccurate. A general equation for a line in the plane is $ax+by=c$ with $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$.

Comment: I understand your point anyway I think that we don’t need function concept to explain why explicit equations doesn’t work. It is indeed a more basic fact. For example I can describe a parabola $x=y^2$ or a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ even if those are not functions. What do you think about it?

Comment: @gimusi We don't, but when the OP says "the general equation for a line is", then that is what I address. That's not the general equation for a line, it's the general equation for a linear function.

Comment: @user1551 You are right. I fixed it.

Comment: @Arthur Got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the meaning of slope of a line? This means take two points on the line where $x$ co-ordinates differ by 1, and see how much the $y$ co-ordinates differ for those two points.

For example, if $(3,7)$ and $(4,23)$ are two points on the line the difference $23-7=16$ is the slope of the line connecting them.

In the case of a line parallel to the $y$-axis *all the points have the same $x$ co-ordinate*.  So slope is undefined. The equation is $x=c$, the constant value of $x$-coordinate.